Listen for iframe parent messages in godot
I am trying to listen for messages from parent in my iframe game window.
The following code could be the right approach?
func _ready():
  var window = JavaScriptBridge.get_interface("window")

  var callback = JavaScriptBridge.create_callback(on_message_received)
  window.addEventListener("message", callback)

func on_message_received(event):
    print("Message received in godot. ")

Actually this is not working (the function on_message_received is not fired), but the following is working:
JavaScriptBridge.eval("
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
               console.log('LISTEN')
            })
    ")


I've fixed it moving the definition of callback as a property of my script so it won't get freed.
var callback = JavaScriptBridge.create_callback(on_message_received)

func _ready():
  var window = JavaScriptBridge.get_interface("window")

  window.addEventListener("message", callback)

func on_message_received(event):
    print("Message received in godot. ")

